# Linq group by new collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem to glue fragments of one call to one meta object with List where stored fragments of this call. So there be a bunch of calls (IEnumerable) which can have one or more fragments. After gluing I will process and convert fragments to one audio file. Now I'm solving this task with a foreach. But I think I can do it with linq.
I have class:

```
IEnumerable<CallImporterRow> CallImporterData
public string AudioFileName { get; set; }
public int FragmentStorageId { get; set; }
public string FragmentSubDirectory { get; set; }
etc...
```

And for future processing I need to create a new collection with few properties from main class in example:

```
public class CallKeys : Fragment
    {
        public int CallKey { get; set; }
        public int CallKeyDay { get; set; }
    }
public class Fragment
{
public int StorageId { get; set; }
public string SubDirectory { get; set; }
public string Filename { get; set; }
public string TargetFilename { get; set; }
public int Section { get; set; }
public int Rows { get; set; }
}
```

First of all I'm transforming my collection of CallImporterRow's to new collection CallKeys:

```
List<CallKeys> keys = CallImporterData
            .Select(x =>
                {
                    string[] k = x.CallUserDef.Split('_');
                    return new CallKeys
                    {
                        CallKey = int.Parse(k[0]),
                        CallKeyDay = int.Parse(k[1]),
                        StorageId = x.FragmentStorageId,
                        SubDirectory = x.FragmentSubDirectory,
                        Filename = x.FragmentFilename,
                        TargetFilename = x.AudioFileName,
                        Section = x.Section,
                        Rows = x.Rows,
                    };
                })
            .ToList();
```

And after that i should group by CallKey and CallKeyDay and grouped items should be part of < CallKeys > keys.Fragment.

It should looks like that:
IEnumerable< CallImporterRow > => IEnumerable< CallKeys > => CallKeys.IEnumerable< Fragment > (Groupped by CallKey and CallKeyDay)

**#UPD 1**
here is how it should looks like.
[image]

Comment: So, what is your question? Does `GroupBy(ck => new { ck.CallKey, ck.CallKeyDay })` answer it?

Comment: @NetMage I want a "one liner" without doing foreach loop to manually group by data. Maybe  I'm doing something wrong but adding GroupBy before List() gives me an error.  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<<anonymous type: int CallKey, int CallKeyDay>, CallKeys>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CallKeys>'

Comment: A little more clarification groupped collection should be placed in plain collection.

Comment: I am afraid that is incredibly unclear. What does "grouped items should be part of < CallKeys > keys.Fragment" mean in C# terms?

Comment: @NetMage I'm added screenshot, hope this is helpfull. So main idea is: from first big collection find items with the same keys create new object with some meta info and place all this items(with  same keys) to list inside this object.

Comment: Screen shots are never helpful - can you show some C# code? C# is a language of types - what is the type of the result?